# How to assign an OleVariant with RTTI? // Convert an OleVariant or a Variant to a TValue with specific TTypeKind or TRTTIType in mind?

Tags: delphi, rtti, variant, spring4d

I have an `OleVariant` or a `Variant` value that, for example, was read with `IXMLNode.GetAttributeNS`, making it a "String" (`varOleStr` or `varString`), and I would like to write that value with, for example, `TRTTIField.SetValue`, requiring a `TValue` assignment-compatible to `TRTTIField.FieldType: TRTTIType`.

For the base types (along `TVarType` and `TRTTIType.TypeKind: TTypeKind`), instead of making each a single case: `case VarType(Value) and varTypeMask of varXXXX: ... end`, I am looking for a general way to convert from `OleVariant` or `Variant` to a `TValue` that then is assignment-compatible to a specific `TRTTIType`.

What is the way to transition values between the Variant and the RTTI world?

Also, the Spring4D library is part of the project, in case that helps.

---

Update:

Technically I am looking for `Convert` in the following code (converting in the Variant world):

```
var
  Left: TRTTIField;
  Right: OleVariant;
  Temp: TValue;
  Instance: Pointer;
begin
  { Examples: varOleStr --> varXXXX --> assignment-compatible TValue }

  Right := 'False'; // varOleStr, as read with IXMLNode.GetAttributeNS
  Right := Convert(Right, Left.FieldType); // making it possibly varBoolean
  Temp := TValue.FromVariant(Right); // tkEnumeration, like Left.FieldType.TypeKind

  Right := '2'; // varOleStr, as read with IXMLNode.GetAttributeNS
  Right := Convert(Right, Left.FieldType); // making it possibly varInteger
  Temp := TValue.FromVariant(Right); // tkInteger, like Left.FieldType.TypeKind

  Right := '3.1415'; // varOleStr, as read with IXMLNode.GetAttributeNS
  Right := Convert(Right, Left.FieldType); // making it possibly varDoiuble
  Temp := TValue.FromVariant(Right); // tkFloat, like Left.FieldType.TypeKind

  Right := 'Hello!'; // varOleStr, as read with IXMLNode.GetAttributeNS
  Right := Convert(Right, Left.FieldType); // making it possibly varOleStr
  Temp := TValue.FromVariant(Right); // tkUString, like Left.FieldType.TypeKind

  { ... and an assignment: }

  Left.SetValue(Instance, Temp);
end;
```

I have found [`VariantChangeTypeEx`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/VarUtils.VariantChangeTypeEx), however, I do not know how to relate `Left.FieldType` to it to make the subsequent code work. -- I also would not mind to convert in the RTTI world and instead start out with `Temp := TValue.FromVariant(Right)` (`tkUString`) and then reach assignment compatibility somehow; so `Temp.Kind` would become `tkEnumeration`/Boolean, `tkFloat`,... as given by `Left.FieldType.TypeKind`.

How to assign a Variant with RTTI? Or, how to convert a Variant to a TValue to then assign it?

Note: [`RTTIField.SetValue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/de/System.Rtti.TRttiField.SetValue) will fail with an `EInvalidCast` if field type and value type differ in nature, as the RTTI will not attempt to change the value's nature. My difficulty here is to reach assignment compatibility.

---

Update: Given the answer, the following code sketches my solution:

```
procedure (const Value: Pointer; const RTTIField: TRTTIField; const XMLNode: IXMLNode);
var
  Temp1: OLEVariant;
  Temp2: TValue;
begin
  Assert(XMLNode.HasAttribute(Ref, Namespace));
  Temp1 := XMLNode.GetAttributeNS(Ref, Namespace);
  Temp2 := TValue.FromVariant(Temp1);
  Temp2 := Temp2.Convert(RTTIField.FieldType.Handle{, FormatSettings}); // in Spring.TValueHelper
  RTTIField.SetValue(Value, Temp2);
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in type casts in TValue will not help you here as they only allow those types that are explicitly compatible (i.e. assignable). Technically if you store the Variant inside the TValue without "unpacking" it which is what `FromVariant` does internally it should be able to cast the Variant to anything it usually can be cast/converted to. However there are is at least one issue with casting a Variant holding 'True' or 'False' to a Boolean (see https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-20160)

However since you are already using Spring4D you can use its improved TValue type conversion feature.

Just use the `Convert` method from the `TValueHelper` in `Spring.pas`.

There you can pass a PTypeInfo (which would be `Left.FieldType.Handle` in your code) and optionally a `TFormatSettings` - by default it will use the current locale.

Comment: `SetValue(..., TValue.From<Variant>('1'))` will not work with an integer RTTI field because the RTTI internals will just replace the (string) variant (`varString`) with a (string) TValue (`tkUString`) which then is not compatible/assignable to an integer RTTI field (`tkInteger`). Instead, starting with an integer variant would work: `SetValue(..., TValue.From<Variant>(1))`. No passing through the variant, no variant magic employable. -- With Spring4D, I achieved what I wanted, also in a more explicit manner (+TFormatSettings), which I actually prefer. See the update to the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> What is the way to transition values between the Variant and the RTTI world?

Use the built in class function conversion in [System.RTTI.TValue](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Rtti.TValue):

```
myTValue := TValue.FromVariant(myVariant);
```

> Builds a new TValue record from a Variant value.
>
> **FromVariant** is a static method that can be used to build TValue records with a stored Variant value. The Value parameter contains the Variant that will be stored inside the built TValue record.

Comment: Given `VarType(MyVariant)` is always `varOleStr` because it was read as string from XML this will (always) give `MyTValue.Kind = tkUString` (or possibly any string type kind) as `TValue.FromVariant` will maintain the value's nature. However, `RTTIField.FieldType.TypeKind` might not be `tkUString` (or an assignment- compatible type kind), it might be `tkEnumeration`/Boolean or `tkFloat`, for example. Then `RTTIField.SetValue(Instance, MyTValue)` will fail with an `EInvalidCast`, as the RTTI assignment will not attempt to change the value's nature to make it (unpredictably/silently) fit.